# Does the Académie Française set out how to format currencies?

Tags: nombres, ponctuation, typographie, unités

I know Académie Française covers orthography beyond just how to spell words.

I also know Académie Française encompasses differences between the various French-using countries.

I'm interested to know if Académie Française clarifies how to format references to amounts of money, including:

- Whether the currency symbol is to the left or right of the price
- Whether using a symbol such as `$`, `£`, `€` means a different format to using `USD`, `EUR`, `CHF`
- Which symbol to use as thousands separator
- Which symbol to use as decimal point
- Whether different French-using countries differ on any of these points
- Whether the rules also cover the formatting of foreign currencies

There is an article on [Wikipedia which lists in a table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_issues_concerning_the_euro#Summary):

```
€  Language    Euro sign usage

   French      6,28 €
```

But I want to know what the Academy has to say.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some answers:

> Whether the currency symbol is to the left or right of the price

AFAIK, the currency symbol is to the right side of the price: 123 €

> Which symbol to use as thousands separator

Use a thin space for number with more than 3 digit long (i.e. 1 000 €, 10 000 €)

> Which symbol to use as decimal point

ALWAYS use a comma: 123,45 €

> Whether the rules also cover the formatting of foreign currencies

This is valid for any currency and also for any unit: 12 345,67 kg

[Reference Académie Française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#57_strong-em-nombres-criture-lecture-accord-em-strong) (especially §3)

Answer (score 4):

To complete @M42 answer,
I'll add that we should use 1,23 € but use a lot 1€23 in France, to write it like we say it. In particular, the latter is used on many price tags.